# How to collect Terraform plan command output in realtime to display in frontend?

Tags: go, terraform

I'm using [terraform-exec](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-exec) module in my `Go` app to run Terraform CLI commands to `Plan` and `Apply`.

When Terraform `plan` is running I can see its output in `stdout`. I need collect that Terraform `Plan` and `Apply` output from `stdout` to display it somewhere in frontend in realtime.

I can't seem to figure out how to collect that `stdout` output in realtime! checking with community whether there is a better alternative to what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Have you tried using the [SetLogger](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-exec/blob/2b60e5db76d633fdb0326922f6c12f0f065c3fc8/tfexec/terraform.go#L105) or [SetStdout](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-exec/blob/2b60e5db76d633fdb0326922f6c12f0f065c3fc8/tfexec/terraform.go#L113)?

Comment: thanks for pointing them out @Matteo, let me check..

Comment: you're welcome @Muzafar let me know if you find a solution :)

Comment: @Matteo - SetStdout() worked however, it's returning all the logs in one shot! Let's say I run `terraform plan` I want to receive each individual log in streaming fashion instead of getting them all once `terraform plan` is finished. Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Seems does already capture the output of the command (see [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-exec/blob/6ff79245078142204b63aa1d9e6c0790c92945f8/tfexec/cmd_default.go#L11-L27) in the code). Try ask on github for further help, sorry